# sublime 3: Command palette is being closed on any key pressed

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text-3

Something is wrong with my sublime3 (build 3103) setup on Ubuntu (15.10).

When I am triggering command palette (with Shift + Ctrl + p), it appears. But then if I type any key inside (or using arrow keys), it's just being closed. So looks like I can only select actions (commands) using mouse which is quite annoying. I believe same happens with auto completion.

Also it's quite strange that if example if I am searching for files, all works and files palette is not closed on key entry :(.

I was trying to reinstall my sublime from scratch, and was also killing sublime3 folder in ~/.config folder. But it's still the same :(

Comment: UPD: Also I have noticed that if for example I will keep holding Shift (after triggering command palette) it became possible to type text or use arrow keys. But only if you have not released it during the command execution

Comment: If you open the console ctrl+\` and write `sublime.log_commands(True)` and `sublime.log_input(True)` you might get some helpful informations.

Comment: Strange. It (palette) started to work fine after I have opened/closed console.

Comment: That is realy strange.

Comment: Looks like it appears again, and the trick with opening/closing console does not help this time :(. The log is not so verbose:
key evt: down
command: move {"by": "lines", "forward": true}
key evt: shift+control+p
command: show_overlay {"overlay": "command_palette"}
key evt: down
command: move {"by": "lines", "forward": true}
command: drag_select {"event": {"button": 1, "x": 343.5, "y": 673.5}}
command: drag_select {"event": {"button": 1, "x": 337.5, "y": 647.5}}

Comment: Wow. It looks like I have traced the issue :(.
I am using a special Ubuntu wide shortcut, e.g. Num Lock calls calculator. And once this is done, I am getting the issue above. And once Num Lock is called second time everything starts to work fine... huh :)